# Searching Text Against a List Using Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I have a block of text:

> We the People of the United States, in Order to form a more perfect
>   Union, establish Justice, insure domestic Tranquility, provide for the
>   common defence, promote the general Welfare, and secure the
>   Blessings of Liberty to ourselves and our Posterity, do ordain and
>   establish this Constitution for the United States of America.

I then have List containing several key words:

```
List<string> keywords = new List<string>()
{
  "Posterity",
  "Liberty",
  "Order",
  "Dinosaurs"
}
```

Here is my desired usage:

```
List<string> GetOrderOfOccurence(string text, List<string> keywords);
```

So calling GetOrderOfOccurence(preamble, keywords) will return the following in order:

```
{"Order"},
{"Liberty"},
{"Posterity"}
```

This can easily be solved with a for loop on the keywords and a getIndexOf(keyword) on preamble; then push the index into a list and return that.  How would this be done using Regex?  Suppose I wanted to have wildcards in my keywords list?

Does System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches() have something that uses a list of patterns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a single group which contains a collection of string from `keywords` separated by a pipeline <kbd>|</kbd> as a pattern if you would like to match the string using a regular expression. Then, search for strings in `text` that matches this pattern adding them to a new `List<string>` which will be then returned as `GetOrderOfOccurence(string text, List<string> keywords)`

**Example**

```
List<string> GetOrderOfOccurence(string text, List<string> keywords)
{
    List<string> target = new List<string>(); //Initialize a new List of string array of name target
    #region Creating the pattern
    string Pattern = "("; //Initialize a new string of name Pattern as "("
    foreach (string x in keywords) //Get x as a string for every string in keywords
    {
        Pattern +=  x + "|"; //Append the string + "|" to Pattern
    }
    Pattern = Pattern.Remove(Pattern.LastIndexOf('|')); //Remove the last pipeline character from Pattern
    Pattern += ")"; //Append ")" to the Pattern
    #endregion
    Regex _Regex = new Regex(Pattern); //Initialize a new class of Regex as _Regex
    foreach (Match item in _Regex.Matches(text)) //Get item as a Match for every Match in _Regex.Matches(text)
    {
        target.Add(item.Value); //Add the value of the item to the list we are going to return
    }
    return target; //Return the list
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> keywords = new List<string>(){"Posterity", "Liberty", "Order", "Dinosaurs"}; //Initialize a new List<string> of name keywords which contains 4 items
    foreach (string x in GetOrderOfOccurence("We the People of the United States, in Order to form a more perfect Union, establish Justice, insure domestic Tranquility, provide for the common defence, promote the general Welfare, and secure the Blessings of Liberty to ourselves and our Posterity, do ordain and establish this Constitution for the United States of America.", keywords)) //Get x for every string in the List<string> returned by GetOrderOfOccurence(string text, List<string> keywords)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(x); //Writes the string in the output Window
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Order
Liberty
Posterity
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use Regex? Linq can probably do it ok.

Example:

```
private List<string> GetOrderOfOccurence(string text, List<string> keywords)
{
    return keywords.Where(x => text.Contains(x)).OrderBy(x => text.IndexOf(x)).ToList();
}
```

Returns

```
{"Order"},
{"Liberty"},
{"Posterity"}
```